# The number 149 is stored in the byte at address 16

Tags: java, memory, byte, bit

I am reading a book about Java programming and in the first chapter it says: "The number 149 is stored in the byte at address 16" - is storing three characters, the 1, the 4, and the 9 in one byte possible?

Comment: "storing three characters, the 1, the 4, and the 9 in one byte" it's storing _one number_ not three separate characters.

Comment: It Depend on representations, `149` can be an `int`, a `short`, a `char`, a `byte`, a `double`, a `float`, an `Integer`, etc...  or even a `String` -> `"149"`. Could you explain it a little bit more?  What is the title of that book?

Comment: The book is wrong, in Java a `byte` is `signed` and has valid values in the range `-128` to `127`.

Comment: @Javant Java does have a primitive data type of `byte`. It supports values in the range `-128` to `127`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Well im an idiot, and that's what I get for never ever using them in java and forgetting about them. my apologies

Comment: The book's title is "Starting out with Java: Early Objects" - Fourth Edition by Tony Gaddis. In the first chapter, the author focuses on some general information before starting with Java. Here is a portion of the paragraph: "Each byte is assigned a unique number known as an address. The addresses are ordered from lowest to highest. ...The number 149 is stored in the byte at address 16, and the number 72 is stored in the byte at address 23."

Answer (score 0):

No, the size of a character in java is 2 bytes. Thus obviously 6 bytes cannot fit into 1.

I think the book was trying to ask whether the number 149 could fit into a byte, in which yes and no, an unsigned byte can hold a value of 255 at max while a two's complement (signed) byte can only hold a value of 126.

[Info about primitive data type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Answer (score 0):

In General, A byte is 8 bits and can store a number range from 0 to 255.  Bytes are often used in RAW data processing and is how data is stored in memory.  When storing characters or a "String", you are storing a sequence of bytes that represent a sequence of characters.

the number 149 in binary Byte form is 10010101

[Decimal to Binary Converter](http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/decimal-to-binary-converter)

But storing characters are different than storing numbers.  To address you question, storing the characters "1", "4", and "9" in a single byte is not possible, but storing the number 149 is.

Also, the number of bytes that a given character/string uses are highly dependant on which encoding you are using.

[Java String see .getBytes(Charset charset)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

All this being said, a byte in Java is signed.  Its range goes from -128 to +127 inclusive.  A byte can store 256 unique values.  You can think of them as numbers, individual flags, whatever you want.  I have no context to the OP's original problem, but if they are using a Java primitive byte, it cannot by default hold the number 149.  IF you are talking about a sequence of 8 bits, it can.

[Java Primitive Datatypes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Comment: Dude you 're completely wrong. `byte` goes up to 127

Comment: All good.  I was speaking in more broad terms, but since you downvoted my competing answer to yours, I will edit my answer to clarify.

Comment: Just trying to save someone from consuming wrong information

Comment: The problems is that we don't have much context I have to assume that the book is at least giving working code.  What was in the paragraph before this?   There have been plenty of times in high performance applications that I have used the byte field as an signed value did math, then converted the signed value to an unsigned value when the actual value was needed.

Comment: Oh, were you writing Java, because Java has no such thing as `unsigned` except for `char`

Comment: Yes.  Just because the default handling of a byte in java represents a numerical value from -128 to + 127 does not mean that it has to be used or interpreted as such in every singe instance of its usage.  I have done a significant amount of bytes and bit-wise arithmetic on bytes (that the contained data was not "numbers"), for many reasons in high performance systems.

Comment: But bitwise on a `byte` promotes it to an `int` so you 're actually not doing the operation on a "byte"

Comment: You are still not thinking outside of the box my friend.  I don't have the time or desire to hold your hand though it, as we are pretty far off topic.  You are still assuming that the out of the box default functionality that you get in Java is all that there is.  A great deal of that goes out the window when you were dealing with high performance systems, especially in Java.  I had assumed that people would have understood that when I mentioned that, but I was wrong.

Comment: But I do thank you for your input.  I have not been very active on this site as a contributor, so still figuring out the community.

Comment: I see where you coming from

Comment: Thank you for valuable inputs. The book's title is "Starting out with Java: Early Objects" - Fourth Edition by Tony Gaddis. In the first chapter, the author focuses on some general information before starting with Java. Here is a portion of the paragraph: "Each byte is assigned a unique number known as an address [in RAM memory]. The addresses are ordered from lowest to highest. ...The number 149 is stored in the byte at address 16, and the number 72 is stored in the byte at address 23."

Comment: 'byte' might refer to the byte size of an integer

Answer (score 0):

Storing the number 149 and characters '1', '4', and '9' separately are completely different. Storing the character '1' is actually storing its ASCII value 49, and the ASCII value 52, and 57 represent '4' and '9 respectively. The size of each character in Java is 2 bytes. So therefore 3 characters with a total size of 6 cannot fit into a single byte.

The byte data type is only 8 bits, and therefore it can store numbers from -128 to +127. That means the maximum value for a byte (Byte.Max_VALUE) is 127, and since 149 is bigger than 127, therefore it cannot fit into a byte, and you have to at least use a short to store 149. A short is 2 bytes in java.

I highly encourage you to read this Java documentation on data types. It's very short, but pretty useful to understand everything about data types.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: Yes, ASCII is a character set that includes the the digit characters 0-9, and  its one encoding stores each of them in one byte. But, what does ASCII have to do with Java? Follow your reference and look at `char`.